# Using 'Insert Into' with an 'update' keyword in an Explicit Cursor

Tags: oracle, plsql, plsqldeveloper

Running the script below, produces the error:

*"Error report -
ORA-06550: line 19, column 15:
PL/SQL: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
ORA-06550: line 19, column 1:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:
"*

```
DECLARE
h_d_regionID departments.region%TYPE;
h_l_countryID locations.country_id%TYPE;

CURSOR DCursor IS
SELECT  d.region --,l.country_id
FROM locations l 
inner join departments d
on d.location_id = l.location_id
FOR UPDATE;
BEGIN
OPEN DCursor;
LOOP
FETCH DCursor INTO h_l_countryID;
EXIT WHEN DCursor%NOTFOUND;
/* Delete the current tuple: */
--DELETE FROM departments.region WHERE CURRENT OF DCursor;
/* Insert the reverse tuple: */
INSERT INTO d.region VALUES(h_d_regionID);

END LOOP;
/* Free cursor used by the query. */
CLOSE DCursor;
END;
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Obviously there's no table `d.region`, as error points you to exact code line. You need to `insert into <table_name>`. Please, describe, what do you want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have used the table name in the `INSERT INTO` statement with an alias (D).

The Following code should work (See inline comment for solution)

```
DECLARE
    H_D_REGIONID    DEPARTMENTS.REGION%TYPE;
    H_L_COUNTRYID   LOCATIONS.COUNTRY_ID%TYPE;
    CURSOR DCURSOR IS
    SELECT D.REGION --,l.country_id
      FROM LOCATIONS     L
     INNER JOIN DEPARTMENTS   D
    ON D.LOCATION_ID = L.LOCATION_ID
    FOR UPDATE;

BEGIN
    OPEN DCURSOR;
    LOOP
        FETCH DCURSOR INTO H_L_COUNTRYID;
        EXIT WHEN DCURSOR%NOTFOUND;
/* Delete the current tuple: */
--DELETE FROM departments.region WHERE CURRENT OF DCursor;
/* Insert the reverse tuple: */
        --INSERT INTO D.REGION VALUES ( H_D_REGIONID ); --issue is with this line
        INSERT INTO REGION VALUES ( H_D_REGIONID ); -- removed the D. before table name
    END LOOP;
/* Free cursor used by the query. */

    CLOSE DCURSOR;
END;
```

Also, Please note that you are using the `H_D_REGIONID` in the `INSERT` statement but it is not initialized or assigned any value.

Comment: If this answer solved your issue then you can accept it so that this question is marked as resolved.